# Firebase Login multiple provider with same email

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want my user who logged In first using FB to be able to log out and log in again using his/her google (same email).

What should I do? I read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking ,but I don't quite understand. I thought the linking is to link accounts, regardless of the email.

While what I'm thinking is firebase identify user by email, so if I successfully log in and out from FB or Google by using same email, then firebase should know its the same user.

in the account-linking docs above, says that we need to get the credential/tokenID and call linkwithcredential , like this :

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

my questions are:

1. where I call this ? do I need to call it every login ?
2. then do I also need to get the credential for every provider each time I login ?

Comment: I don't suppose you got an answer to this?  I am also confused by the terminology in the docs.  One would think this would just be handled by firebase in the backend.  But since they don't.... ?